# group by in group by and average

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, mean

I have a dataframe like this:

```
cluster  org      time
   1      a       8
   1      a       6
   2      h       34
   1      c       23
   2      d       74
   3      w       6
```

I would like to calculate the average of time per org per cluster.

Expected result:

```
cluster mean(time)
1       15 #=((8 + 6) / 2 + 23) / 2
2       54 #=(74 + 34) / 2
3       6
```

I do not know how to do it in Pandas, can anybody help?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

If you want to first take mean on the combination  of `['cluster', 'org']` and then take mean on `cluster` groups, you can use:

```
In [59]: (df.groupby(['cluster', 'org'], as_index=False).mean()
            .groupby('cluster')['time'].mean())
Out[59]:
cluster
1          15
2          54
3           6
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

If you want the mean of `cluster` groups only, then you can use:

```
In [58]: df.groupby(['cluster']).mean()
Out[58]:
              time
cluster
1        12.333333
2        54.000000
3         6.000000
```

You can also use `groupby` on `['cluster', 'org']` and then use `mean()`:

```
In [57]: df.groupby(['cluster', 'org']).mean()
Out[57]:
               time
cluster org
1       a    438886
        c        23
2       d      9874
        h        34
3       w         6
```

Comment: But I want one number per cluster ( average of average of time per org ). So the result is only cluster and average time

Answer (score 21):

I would simply do this, which literally follows what your desired logic was:

```
df.groupby(['org']).mean().groupby(['cluster']).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to reshape the dataframe using `pivot_table()` then take `mean()`. Note that it's necessary to pass `aggfunc='mean'` (this averages `time` by `cluster` and `org`).

```py
df.pivot_table(index='org', columns='cluster', values='time', aggfunc='mean').mean()
```

Another possibility is to use `level` parameter of `mean()` after the first `groupby()` to aggregate:

```py
df.groupby(['cluster', 'org']).mean().mean(level='cluster')
```