# How can I plot an average line for a scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have the df below and I want to create 3 scatter plots (days vs A, days vs B, days vs C) displaying all data points plus a line that goes through the average for each day.

`plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,3], 'b')` for example gives me a line that goes through each single point (3rd plot), but instead I want a line that goes through the average value.

Here is my code:

```
data=np.array([[1,4.4,40.1,55],
           [1,4.5,40.6,45.6],
           [1,4.4,41.5,61.3],
           [4,10,26,79.4],
           [4,11.2,25.3,80.9],
           [4,10.5,23.6,84],
           [10,5.6,12.7,58.2],
           [10,6,10.9,60.8],
           [10,7.3,8.7,70.5,],
           [15,2.5,5.4,98.7],
           [15,2.7,6.2,95.3],
           [15,2.8,4.7,88.9],
           [25,0.8,3.3,25.4],
           [25,0.5,1,28.6],
           [25,1,5,23.6]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data[:,0:],columns=['days','A','B','C'])

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1) 
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1], 'ro')
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2) 
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,2], 'ro')
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3) 
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,3], 'ro')
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,3], 'b')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group your values and then plot the average. The method to group and find the mean was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average) answer. The rest was the plotting part.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data[:,0:],columns=['days','A','B','C'])
df_mean = df.groupby('days')['A','B','C'].mean()

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1) 
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1], 'ro')
plt.plot(df_mean.index, df_mean['A'], '-r')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2) 
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,2], 'ro')
plt.plot(df_mean.index, df_mean['B'], '-r')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3) 
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,3], 'ro')
plt.plot(df_mean.index, df_mean['C'], '-r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a vector with the mean value and plot it:

```
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,3].mean() + np.zeros_like(df.iloc[:,3]), 'g--')
```