# How can I assign the type of city to the city in a list inside a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with city, total highways per city, tolls per driver, and city type. I have to get the total highways per city, average tolls per city and the city type for each city in a separate DataFrame so I can eventually plot using scatter plot. There are about 2500 rows of data.

---

I able to to get total highways per city and average tolls per city using the .mean() function, but I can figure out how to assign the city type for each city.

---

What would be the best way to assign the city type for each city?

---

Sample of how the original DataFrame looks like:

```
City          Total Highways  Tolls per Driver  City Type
Miami          5                1.75               Suburban
Miami          5                2.25               Suburban
Weston         3                3.50               Rural
Weston         3                1.00               Rural
Weston         3                5.75               Rural
Weston         3                2.25               Rural
Ft Lauderdale  6                6.00               Urban
Ft Lauderdale  6                3.50               Urban
Ft Lauderdale  6                4.50               Urban
Ft Lauderdale  6                4.25               Urban
Ft Lauderdale  6                3.25               Urban
Ft Lauderdale  6                1.00               Urban
```

---

Sample of how the new DataFrame should look like:

```
City            Total Highways  Average Tolls  City Type
Miami           5               2.00           Suburban   
Weston          3               3.13           Rural
Ft Lauderdale   6               3.75           Urban
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas : group by in group by and average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average)

Comment: `df.groupby('City').agg({'Total Highways': 'mean', 'Tolls per Driver': 'mean', 'City Type': 'first'})`

Comment: @user3483203 thank you! worked like a charm. I'm fairly new to python and was working on this for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different aggregation functions for each column, so this should work:

```
df.groupby('City').agg({'Total Highways': lambda x:x.iloc[0], 'Tolls per Driver': np.mean, 'City Type': lambda x:x.iloc[0]})
```

**Edit**: Without lambda it looks even better:

```
df.groupby('City').agg({'Total Highways': 'first', 'Tolls per Driver': 'mean', 'City Type': 'first'})
```

Comment: Use `first` instead of  a lamba function