# How do I get an average grouped by a variable in numpy and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
Year    Month    Day    Delay
2019    1        4      60
2018    1        10     50
2018    1        30     25
2019    1        16     42
2017    1        14     0
2019    1        16     9
2017    1        14     5
```

I want to get the average `Delay` for each `Year`.

I think I need to use `groupby()` but I don't know how to do it for two variables.

In [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average) they don't show how to get a variable by grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, is it `mean`?

```
df.groupby('Year').Delay.mean()

Out[126]:
Year
2017     2.5
2018    37.5
2019    37.0
Name: Delay, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I only want the mean for `Delay`

Comment: @rachelvsamuel: ah, I edited the answer to `mean` only `Delay`