# How to calculate group by in group by and average on elements which are not null?

Tags: python, pandas

I have table which I want to get average of success tests (not NULL) per day.

For example:

```
    f_idx    day     test_result
0       1      1       OK
1       1      1       OK
2       2      7       NULL
3       1      3       NULL
4       2      3       NULL
5       3      1       OK
6       1      3       OK
```

f_ix = 1, have 2 success tests on day 1 and 1 success test on day 3

f_ix = 2, have 0 success tests on day 7 and 0 success test on day 3

f_ix = 3, have 1 success tests on day 1

I expect to get result as:

```
    f_idx    p_res
0       1      (1+1)/2 + (1)/2
1       2      0/1 + 0/1   
2       3      1/1
```

I looked at the post here:
[Python Pandas : group by in group by and average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average)

And tried the first solution of `Zero`, but I'm getting error:
`KeyError Column not found`:

my code:

```
print(df.columns) # I can see the column name test_result)
df.groupby(['f_idx','day']).mean().groupby('f_idx')['test_result'].mean()
```

I'm getting error:

```
Caolumn not found: test_result
```

Comment: no, because on day 3 there is one success and one null

Comment: it's not similar, because here I have 2 groups (f_idx and day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First aggregate `mean` only not missinga values in new column created by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) converted to numbers and then get `sum` per first level, here `f_idx`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(p_res=df['test_result'].notna().view('i1'))
         .groupby(['f_idx','day'])['p_res']
         .mean()
         .sum(level=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   f_idx  p_res
0      1    1.5
1      2    0.0
2      3    1.0
```

Solution working same like aggregation by first level with `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(p_res=df['test_result'].eq('OK').view('i1'))
         .groupby(['f_idx','day'])['p_res']
         .mean()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .sum()
         .reset_index())
```