# In Pandas, how can i split my columns to calculate individual mean prices?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with a huge list of house pricing information. I need to calculate the mean price overall and the most common zip codes. My code does these things fine so far but i need to split the housing now into its various types (of which there are about 5) and i need to calculate the mean price for these individual types.

Comment: groupby housetype and calculate the mean of the groups?

Comment: Probably a dupe of   [pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average)

Comment: I've been trying to implement some of the code suggested in that post but I am getting the wrong output. The groupby function doesn't seem to be grouping the correct column as the output seems to still contain info from other columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column containing the types of house, you can just group for that column ad then compute the mean:

```
avgs = df.groupby('Housetype').mean()
```

Answer (score -1):

Separate them to different dataframes, e.g.

```
df1 = df[df['HouseType'] == 1]
```

will create a new dataframe with only type1 houses