# How to do the mean and group in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following:

```
table = [['Country', 'Points'], ['Spain', '7'], ['Spain', '9'], ['Germany', '1'], ['Germany', '3']]
```

I want to do the mean of Spain (8) and Germany (2) and group them to:

```
table_result = [['Country', 'Points'], ['Spain', '8'], ['Germany', '2']]
```

Comment: You forgot to include the code you attempted, and any errors/issues you encountered.

Comment: Does this solves your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average

Comment: These are lists not pandas objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

table = [['Country', 'Points'], ['Spain', '7'], ['Spain', '9'], ['Germany', '1'], ['Germany', '3']]
df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0])

df['Points'] = df['Points'].astype(int)
grouped_df = df.groupby('Country')
mean_df = grouped_df.mean()
```

**Output:**

```
print(mean_df)
         Points
Country        
Germany     2.0
Spain       8.0
```