# How to calculate values and stored in a particular column based on date using Python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which contains date,product,quantity and numbers columns.Based on this dataframe,I want to create a new Dataframe which contains month,year,product,measurement and value columns.I need overall data in each month and corresponding year in new dataframe instead of all dates.

Below images shows the two table:

First:
[image]

I want the table like this:

Second :
[image]

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['01-01-2021', '02-01-2021', '03-01-2021', '01-02-2021', '02-02-2021', '03-02-2021'],
    'product': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple'],
    'quantity': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas : group by in group by and average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328646/python-pandas-group-by-in-group-by-and-average)

Comment: Please provide the code you've tested so far.

Comment: I do not know a solution for this to write code.That is why I asked@WArnold

Comment: Please provide at least part of your data frame as code not as picture. Make it as easy as possible for the community to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok. I will add@ko3

Answer (score 1):

first we need to convert year, month, day, hours

```py
# change the invoice_date format - String to Timestamp format
df['InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.InvoiceDate, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df.insert(loc=2, column='Year_Month', value=df['InvoiceDate'].map(lambda x: 100*x.year + x.month))

df.insert(loc=3, column='Month', value=df.InvoiceDate.dt.month)

# +1 to make Monday=1.....until Sunday=7

df.insert(loc=4, column='Day', value=(df.InvoiceDate.dt.dayofweek)+1)

df.insert(loc=5, column='Hour', value=df.InvoiceDate.dt.hour)
```

Comment: Give me a solution  to add measurement and value column in dataframe @shubham koli